# How to get nth row of Spark RDD?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

Suppose I have an RDD of arbitrary objects. I wish to get the 10th (say) row of the RDD. How would I do that?
One way is to use rdd.take(n) and then access the nth element is the object, but this approach is slow when n is large.

Comment: I believe the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24677180/877069) are also relevant here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know how much it is efficient, as it depends on the current and future optimizations in the Spark's engine, but you can try doing the following:

```
rdd.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2==9).map(_._1).first()
```

The first function transforms the RDD into a pair (value, idx) with idx going from 0 onwards. The second function takes the element with idx==9 (the 10th). The third function takes the original value. Then the result is returned.

The *first* function could be pulled up by the execution engine and influence the behavior of the whole processing. Give it a try.

In any case, if *n* is **very large**, this method is efficient in that it does not require to collect an array of the first *n* elements in the driver node.

Comment: Unfortunately, `zipWithIndex` requires a full pass over the data to calculate the index offset of each partition.  It is still probably your best bet though.

Comment: I tried it and it is slow. Ok for maybe getting one row, but getting several rows, one at a time is very slow

Comment: Why is this so absurdly hard? `.first` is all its takes for the first row...
Serious question.

Answer (score 10):

I haven't checked this for the huge data. But it works fine for me.

> Lets say n=2, I want to access the 2nd element,

```
   data.take(2).drop(1)
```

Comment: You don't want to do this for a large `n` values as it will result in getting the first `n` elements (which is affected by the partitioning...) to the driver code itself... so it can be slow or even impossible to do...

Comment: Agree. Is there any efficient way to do so?

Comment: AFAIK: Nicola Ferraro's answer above contains the best approach we currently have. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27826498/2846609

Answer (score 6):

`RDD.collect()` and  `RDD.take(x)`  both return a list, which supports indexing. So each time we need an element at position N.We can perform any of following two codes:
`RDD.collect()[N-1]`
or
`RDD.take(N)[N-1]`
will work fine when we want element at position N.

Comment: bad idea if you want the billionth row. This brings the entire RDD to the head end, which is almost always the wrong thing to do.